# Изменить значения в столбце после его группировки sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Всем привет.

Знаю, что решение элементарное, но не могу допетрить.

```sql
SELECT person_id, count(score)
FROM score
GROUP BY person_id;
```

Код выдаёт что-то типа такого:

```
person_id  count(score)
---------  ------------
AE-640140  2           
AF-992719  1           
BB-744852  2           
BE-538433  1           
BH-465461  3           
CA-115055  2           
CB-137658  3           
CF-172009  3           
CF-256627  1           
CF-662375  2           
DC-711801  3           
DD-100740  3
```

Как мне в этой выгрузке заменить значения в **count(score)** на 3?

Answer (score 1):

Да прям так и делать:

```
SELECT person_id, 3 as "count(score)"
FROM score
GROUP BY person_id;
```

вывод будет примерно таким:

```
person_id  count(score)
---------  ------------
AE-640140  3           
AF-992719  3           
BB-744852  3           
BE-538433  3           
BH-465461  3           
CA-115055  3           
CB-137658  3           
CF-172009  3           
CF-256627  3           
CF-662375  3           
DC-711801  3           
DD-100740  3
```

Comment: Гениально. Спасибо :)

Comment: гг))) одобрямс)